# gradle in android studio is not selecting the installed sdk

Tags: android

I have started learning android and i'm stuck at something.
I have installed android sdk api 22 and when i'm syncing it with gradle , the following error is popping up:

Failed to find target with hash string 'android-27' in: C:\Users\user
\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk

it says that it is missing android sdk api 27 but i have installed android sdk api 22

why is it not selecting the installed sdk

Comment: Because you specified API 27 in your `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 0):

1.>Uninstall your android studio. remove all folders. and sdk from c drive.just remove all file folder related to android studio.

2.>Download latest android studio from android developer site using below link.
https://developer.android.com/studio/?gclid=CjwKCAiAyrXiBRAjEiwATI95mQYBGcmv_eUPnDUijy-THzdWA_dIIc-6iM1CEZ0w-k02TxfN4wqbXBoCTAYQAvD_BwE

3.Install android studio from downloaded .exe file.

will work fine if android studio will install successfully.
android studio don't need sdk externally.

Answer (score 0):

Check the app/build.gradle file, maybe you specified sdk version 27 on it, you can change it with api 22.

Comment: I have already tried that. after that it is showing that api 28 is missing.